# How to override Session.php in joomla

Tags: joomla3.0

I have to increase session lifetime for individual users. We can achieve this by changing in Session.php file. I'm not changing Session.php file because it's a core file . So I'm trying to override this file.

I used onAfterRoute event

But its not working.
public function onAfterRoute()
{
JLoader::register('JDatabase', JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/camcloud/src/Session.php', true);
}

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.